# Why no deadlock in this scenario?

Tags: c#, .net

So I was happily reading [this](http://ericlippert.com/2013/01/31/the-no-lock-deadlock/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=the-no-lock-deadlock) from Eric Lippert and then, of course, the excellent comments and in them [John Payson](http://ericlippert.com/2013/01/31/the-no-lock-deadlock/#comment-14921) said:

> > a more interesting example might have been to use two static classes, since such a program could deadlock without any visible blocking statements.

and I thought, yeah, that'd be easy so I knocked up this:

```
public static class A
{     
    static A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A.ctor");
        B.Initialize();
        Console.WriteLine("A.ctor.end");
    }

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A.Initialize");
    }
}
public static class B
{
    static B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B.ctor");
        A.Initialize();
        Console.WriteLine("B.ctor.end");
    }

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B.Initialize");
    }

    public static void Go()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Go");
    }
}
```

The output of which (after calling `B.Go()`) is:

```
B.ctor
A.ctor
B.Initialize
A.ctor.end
A.Initialize
B.ctor.end
Go
```

No deadlock and I am am obviously a loser - so to perpetuate the embarrassment, here is my question: why no deadlock here?

It seems to my tiny brain that `B.Initialize` is called **before** the static constructor of `B` has finished and I thought that that was not allowed.

Comment: It might be interesting to see the stacktraces at each point.

Comment: How to you propose to deadlock one thread?  Everything is occurring synchronously...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important point is that there is only one thread involved. Quote from the blog post:

> The static constructor then starts up a new thread. When that thread starts, the CLR sees that a static method is about to be called on a type whose static constructor is "in flight" **another thread**. It immediately blocks the new thread so that the Initialize method will not start until the main thread finishes running the class constructor.

In Erics example, there are two threads waiting for each other. You only have one thread, so there is no waiting happening and as a consequence: no blocking and no deadlock.

Comment: Ah, yes, that would be why I am stupid - of course I cannot deadlock a single thread of execution - I can just, as @pickypg said, produce an unsafe scenario.  Thank you

Comment: Is it clear when static constructor is executed in a new thread and when it does not happen?

Comment: @zespri: Please provide a sample.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: sorry, what are you talking about? Sample of what?

Comment: @zespri: A sample of whatever scenario you meant when you said "when static constructor is executed in a new thread".

Comment: How would I know? It's you posted this "The static constructor then starts up a new thread". We know, that static constructors are guaranteed to be called before first usage of a class. We also know that synchronization is applied when executing a static constructor because it not always obvious for a developer *when* it's executed, so it can be unintentionally called simultaneously from more than one place. So I asked you to clarify, when does that happen so that "The static constructor then starts up a new thread".

Comment: @zespri: Aha, now I understood what you meant. The thing with the thread is a direct quote from Eric's blog post that the OP linked in his question. You have to read it to understand my answer, I guess.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a deadlock because you're not doing anything that should block, nor are you doing anything that should break.

You are not using any resources from `A` within `B`, and vice versa. As a result, your circular dependency is "safe" in the sense that nothing will explode.

If you trace the path that your printouts show, then nothing should block:

1. Call `Go` (I suspect)
2. Enter `B` (`static` constructor) as it is not initialized.
3. Print out
4. Use `A.Initialize()`
5. `A`'s `static` constructor is required to execute first
6. Print out
7. Use `B.Initialize()`
8. `B` does not need to initialize, but it's not in a completed state (fortunately no variables are being set, so nothing breaks)
9. Print out, then return
10. Print out (from `A`'s `static` constructor), then return
11. `A.Initialize()` can finally be called because `A` is initialized
12. Print out, then return
13. Print out (from `B`'s `static` constructor), then return
14. `Go`

The only thing that you really did was present the potential for an unsafe state: accessing a class whose constructor had not finished executing.  That is unsafe code, and while not blocking, definitely represents a broken state.

Answer (score 1):

Why you think there should be a deadlock. Static constructors are called only once. No matter how many time you execute statement `B.Initialize();` it will call the static constructor of class B only first time when B is referred. See more on static constructors [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The static methods are called only once and once loaded those are not called again.
It would be a deadlock if  `A.Initialize()` method called `B.Initialize()` method and vice versa.

So any class first loaded into the memory the static block gets executed and after that any subsequent called to it - because the class is already loaded so static block doesn't get executed.

Comment: If A.Initialize called B.Initialize and vice versa wouldn't that cause a StackOverflowException, not a deadlock?

Comment: since there is no common resource here that the 2 classes are referring to so there is no concept of deadlock - the only thing that might happen is to fill the stack.

Comment: That's obviously recursion but no deadlock.

Answer (score -3):

The class instance is actually created before constructor call, thus there's no need to execute constructor anymore.

Comment: where are we creating objects first of all inorder to execute the constructors - since we are using only static methods and static blocks there is no concept of constructors.